# group array by groups and sort by position

Tags: javascript, arrays, position, grouping

I have an array.  I need to group this array by groups and sort by position.  I tied to create a new array with group names as keys and values as sorted array grouped by group, but didn't work well.  How can I do this?

```
a = [
    {id:1,name:'qw'group:'C',name:'hite',position:'1'},
    {id:2,name:'qwe'group:'B',name:'ite',position:'2'},
    {id:3,name:'qwer'group:'A',name:'ite',position:'3'},
    {id:4,name:'qer'group:'D',name:'te',position:'4'},
    {id:5,name:'wer'group:'C',name:'whit',position:'5'},
    {id:6,name:'er'group:'B',name:'whi',position:'6'},
]

function groupDo(array){                
  var groups = [];
  for (var i in array){
    groups[array[i].group] = array[i].group;
  }
  for (var i in array){
    if (groups[array[i].group] == array[i].group){
      groups[array[i].group] = array[i];
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple straight forward answer:

```
var sortByPosition = function(obj1, obj2) {
  return obj1.position - obj2.position;
};

var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'qw', group: 'C', name: 'hite', position: '1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'qwe', group: 'B', name: 'ite', position: '2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'qwer', group: 'A', name: 'ite', position: '3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'qer', group: 'D', name: 'te', position: '4' },
  { id: 5, name: 'wer', group: 'C', name: 'whit', position: '5' },
  { id: 6, name: 'er', group: 'B', name: 'whi', position: '6' },
];

var grouped = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
  if(!grouped[arr[i].group]) {
    grouped[arr[i].group] = [];
  }
  grouped[arr[i].group].push(arr[i]);
}

for (var group in grouped) {
  grouped[group] = grouped[group].sort(sortByPosition);
}

console.log(grouped);
```

When you want to do stuff like this though, it's usually recommended to use a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), so that you don't have to "reinvent the wheel". Here's how it would look like using one of these libraries:

```
var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'qw', group: 'C', name: 'hite', position: '1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'qwe', group: 'B', name: 'ite', position: '2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'qwer', group: 'A', name: 'ite', position: '3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'qer', group: 'D', name: 'te', position: '4' },
  { id: 5, name: 'wer', group: 'C', name: 'whit', position: '5' },
  { id: 6, name: 'er', group: 'B', name: 'whi', position: '6' },
];

var grouped = _.groupBy(arr, 'group');

for (var group in grouped) {
  _.sortBy(grouped[group], 'position');
}

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: While a utility library like lodash might be good if you load it deferred and you use all of its functionality, it will seriously penalize your user if you load gigantic libraries synchronously just to use only 1 or 2 of that libraries functions.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery this is a general JavaScript question/answer. Where does it say this code will run run in a web browser? It could be running on the server side. Also, if you're concerned about adding a whole library when you just want one single function, you can install it by doing `npm install --save lodash.sortby`. `lodash` publishes each function as an individual package.

Comment: It does not matter where the code is running in the browser or on a server. The simple fact of the matter is that the more libraries like lodash you use, the worse your applications performance. On NodeJS, loading the lodash library will keep it in memory cache incaseif it needs to be required again. In the browser, it will force the user to download the entire library. But, I do agree that it would likely not be a problem to load that lodash function indivually.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go!

```
a = [
    {id:1,name:'qw',group:'C',name:'hite',position:'1'},
    {id:2,name:'qwe',group:'B',name:'ite',position:'2'},
    {id:3,name:'qwer',group:'A',name:'ite',position:'3'},
    {id:4,name:'qer',group:'D',name:'te',position:'4'},
    {id:5,name:'wer',group:'C',name:'whit',position:'5'},
    {id:6,name:'er',group:'B',name:'whi',position:'6'},
]

function groupAndSort(array, groupField, sortField) {
    var groups = {}; // This object will end being keyed by groups, and elements will be arrays of the rows within the given array, which have been sorted by the sortField
    // Put all the rows into groups
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var row = array[i];
        var groupValue = row[groupField];
        groups[groupValue] = groups[groupValue] || [];
        groups[groupValue].push(row);
    }
    // Sort each group
    for (var groupValue in groups) {
        groups[groupValue] = groups[groupValue].sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[sortField] - b[sortField];
        });
    }
    // Return the results
    return groups;
}

var groupedAndSorted = groupAndSort(a, "group", "position");
```

Comment: Looks like I double-posted with @Felipe :( My solution lets you group and sort by arbitrary field names, and also keeps variables within the scope of a function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group objects, first think about what the resulting data would look like.  Maybe something like this?

```
var grouped = {
    A : [
         {id:3,name:'qwer', group:'A',name:'ite',position:'3'}
    ],
    B : [],
    C : [],
    D : []
};
```

And so on.  To transform a list into an object, consider using .reduce().
.reduce() takes a function as its first argument, and a resulting object as the second.  The function iterates through each element of the array and reduces it into the given object.

```
var data = [
  {id:1,name:'qw', group:'C',name:'hite',position:'1'},
  {id:2,name:'qwe', group:'B',name:'ite',position:'2'},
  {id:3,name:'qwer', group:'A',name:'ite',position:'3'},
  {id:4,name:'qer', group:'D',name:'te',position:'4'},
  {id:5,name:'wer', group:'C',name:'whit',position:'5'},
  {id:6,name:'er', group:'B',name:'whi',position:'6'},
]


// acc is the accumulated object, x is each element of the array
data.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    // first check if the given group is in the object
    acc[x.group] = acc[x.group] ?  acc[x.group].concat(x) : [x];

    return acc;

}, {});  // this is the resulting object
```

Now all you need to do is use the built in sort to order the resulting arrays.  You could do this by iterating through the keys of the resulting object and applying .sort() to each array.  .sort() takes a function as an argument which accesses the data and provides a comparison function.

```
// a and b are elements of the array
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.position > b.position) {
      return -1;
  } else if (b.position > a.position) {
      return 1;
  } else {
      return 0;
  }
});
```

And you would implement it like so

```
var result = Object.keys(data).map(function(d){
    return d.sort(f); // f is the function above
});
```